# searchview setQuery not working?

Tags: android, searchview

I need to set the text for search view with strings that is captured by my camera, the text captured has been successfully converted into string and i want to make transfer the string to the searchview, here is my code, but turned out that everytime I want to set text for the search view, it crashes.

```
 String value="";
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
         value = extras.getString("result");
         searchView.setQuery(value, true);
         //Log.i("search", value);
         searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
         //searchView.setQuery("", false);             
         this.isFirstStart = false;
         Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the error message from LogCat, please? Also make sure that you get a valid string from extras.getString("result"). If not set properly it will return null and might make your app crash.